# How to order imports in a Vue file?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I am using Prettier but it doesn't format the order of imports.

For example, when using Go in VS Code, I can import stuff in whatever order but Gofmt will always reorder it in the right order - I guess it is part of the official Go extension for VS Code.

How to achieve something like that in Vue in VS Code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like [Volar](https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/798#issuecomment-997232047) supports this feature (Command palette + `Organize Imports`), it's the recommended extensions for VScode and Vue3 anyway. Vetur being for Vue2 mainly.

This can be done with [Eslint too](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/sort-imports). Which is the official linter for anything related to Vue + JS.

People tend to not have a lot of imports overall in Vue3, thanks to auto-imports of Vue methods + components etc. There is maybe more magic overall, as shown by the [`unplugin` packages](https://antfu.me/projects).

You could use this extension I guess: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=amatiasq.sort-imports

Answer (score 2):

There's also a prettier plugin that supports formatting imports in vue files: https://github.com/IanVS/prettier-plugin-sort-imports (I'm the maintainer).